# Android Portions of TextView Invisible

Tags: android, textview

I have some text views in a table layout. When I click a button in my layout parts of the textviews disappear. I have tried restarting eclipse and the emulator a few times, but nothing has changed. I am completely stumped. Any suggestions for why this may be happening? I have posted a before and after screenshot and my xml code for the table layout

Before Click

[image]

After Click

[image]

Portions of the XML Code...

```
 <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_rank"
                android:stretchColumns="1" >

             <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:text="Public"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Parties Thrown:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PublicPartyAmount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" parties"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Average Score:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PublicAverageScore"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" points"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Biggest Party:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PublicBiggestParty"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" guests"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Highest Score:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PublicHighestScore"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" points"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:text="Private"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Parties Thrown:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PrivatePartyAmount"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" parties"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Average Score:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PrivateAverageScore"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" points"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#acacac"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Biggest Party:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PrivateBiggestParty"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" guests"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.35"
                        android:text="Highest Score:"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_PrivateHighestScore"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=" guests"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="8dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
```

Comment: It may be useful to see what the Button does.

Comment: Button basically makes an EditText appear, which shifts down the rest of the page.